# Create a list including row name, column name and the value from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
    A   B   C  
A   1   3   0    
B   3   2   5     
C   0   5   4
```

All I want is shown below:

```
my_list = [('A','A',1),('A','B',3),('A','C',0),('B','B',2),('B','C',5),('C','C',4)]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC, you can do:

```
df.stack().reset_index().agg(tuple,1).tolist()
```

---

```
[('A', 'A', 1),
 ('A', 'B', 3),
 ('A', 'C', 0),
 ('B', 'A', 3),
 ('B', 'B', 2),
 ('B', 'C', 5),
 ('C', 'A', 0),
 ('C', 'B', 5),
 ('C', 'C', 4)]
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but is there any solution to remove the duplicates like ('A','B',3) and ('B','A',3)?

Answer (score 3):

I feel like make the `index` and value different should be more clear

```
[*df.stack().iteritems()]
[(('A', 'A'), 1), (('A', 'B'), 3), (('A', 'C'), 0), (('B', 'A'), 3), (('B', 'B'), 2), (('B', 'C'), 5), (('C', 'A'), 0), (('C', 'B'), 5), (('C', 'C'), 4)]
```

Or

```
df.reset_index().melt('index').values.tolist()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and use [`to_records`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_records.html) to obtain a record array from the result:

```
df.stack().to_frame().to_records().tolist()
# [('A', 'A', 1), ('A', 'B', 3), ('A', 'C', 0), ('B', 'A', 3),...
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi i think you could done it with splitting the list into parts

```
with dataframe as data:
    for line in data.readlines():
        parts = line.split(' ') # split line into parts
        part1 = (parts[0])
        part2 = (parts[1])
        part3 = (parts[2])
```

Answer (score 1):

Can also use [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
In [1638]: df.unstack().to_frame().to_records().tolist()
Out[1638]: 
[('A', 'A', 1),
 ('A', 'B', 3),
 ('A', 'C', 0),
 ('B', 'A', 3),
 ('B', 'B', 2),
 ('B', 'C', 5),
 ('C', 'A', 0),
 ('C', 'B', 5),
 ('C', 'C', 4)]
```